How to run flask-ngrok in google colab? Getting error: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
I initially ran the following code in google colab cells and even created an ngrok account to get the authtoken.
!pip install flask-ngrok
!pip install pyngrok==4.1.1
!ngrok authtoken 'TOKEN_ID'

from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from flask import Flask, request
import pickle
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return "Hello World"

app.run()

When running the code, I get this output below. When watching other tutorials, I see that there is another ngrok link that shows up where the server can be accessed but I dont see that here. I get the connection issue but downloaded and imported the right libraries as mentioned above. Is there anything else I can do?
* Serving Flask app '__main__'
 * Debug mode: off
INFO:werkzeug:WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
INFO:werkzeug:Press CTRL+C to quit
Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 791, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 497, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 395, in request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 243, in connect
    self.sock = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7c5a06984880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 845, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4040): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/tunnels (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7c5a06984880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1378, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask_ngrok.py", line 70, in start_ngrok
    ngrok_address = _run_ngrok()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask_ngrok.py", line 35, in _run_ngrok
    tunnel_url = requests.get(localhost_url).text  # Get the tunnel information
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4040): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/tunnels (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7c5a06984880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))


Configure a token here:
https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken
Use the following code:
from pyngrok import ngrok
from flask import Flask

ngrok_token = 'ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'
port = 5000
ngrok.set_auth_token(ngrok_token)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def root():
  return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    public_url = ngrok.connect(port).public_url
    print(public_url)
    app.run(port=port)
  finally:
    ngrok.disconnect(public_url=public_url)

